# ¿Como validar este string como una expresión? Javascript

Tags: javascript

en mi sitio los Usuarios deben agregar, en un campo, una formula por ejemplo:

```
X>1000
```

o

```
X<100,5
```

La X despues será remplazada por un número que el usuario no ingresa, el usuario ingresa solo la "X" y el signo "<" o ">" y siguiendo de un numero con o sin decimales. No sé como validar ese string con una expresión

Lo unico que tengo de codigo para probar es esto (aunque sé que esta todo malo):

```
 console.log( /^X[<|>]([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)*$/.test('X>1000000.023827.34723845') );
```

Muchas gracias, por favor ayudenme :)

Comment: No te conviene hacerlo con operadores lógicos? `if (x > 1000 || x < 100.5) {}`?

Comment: En realidad, puedes hacerlo con operadores lógicos.

Comment: Dada tu explicación, realmente no es necesaria una expresión regular aquí, más bien estás complicando el proceso intentando agregar una

Comment: No, pues "1000" y "100.5" son numeros que ingresa el usuario tambien. El usuario puede ingresar los numeros que desee. Ellos crearán la formula, y el sistema que tengo lo interpretará. Quizá no me este explicando bien :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Un expresión regular para lograrlo sería la siguiente:

```
/^X[<>]\d+(\.\d+)?$/
```

Por otro lado, dado que obviamente necesitas "*parsear*" la cadena, podrías modificar la expresión regular agrupando cada parte de la formula y usar [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/match) para obtener dicha info.

#### Ejemplo:

```
/^(X)([<>])(\d+(\.\d+)?)$/
// Solo agregamos parentesis para agrupar la info
```

#### Demo

```js
let formulaRE = /^(X)([<>])(\d+(\.\d+)?)$/i;

document.getElementById('formula')
  .addEventListener('input', function() {
  
    let match = this.value.match(formulaRE);
    if (match) {
      console.log('X: ' + match[1]);
      console.log('Operador: ' + match[2]);
      console.log('Numero: ' + match[3]);
    }
  });
```

```html
<input id="formula"/>
```

Comment: Gracias men, muchas gracias! :) Si me sirve...